# How can I share a query between a static page and a generated one?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

In Gatsby, both static pages (ie. components defined in `/pages`) and dynamic pages (ie. "pages" created in `gatsby-node.j`) have a way to depend on GraphQL data by exporting a query variable.  However, the static page wants a `graphql`-tagged string, whereas the dynamic page only wants a string:

```
// /pages/index.js
export const query = graphql`*QUERY*`;
```

vs.

```
// gatsby-node.js
export const query = `*QUERY*`;
```

If I try to use string interpolation to use the string with the tag:

```
export const query = graphql`${actualQuery}*`;
```

I get an error, because that tag doesn't allow string interpolation.

I realize that I *could* just keep two copies of the query: one as a plain string, and then an identical "tagged" copy ... but surely there's some way to avoid this duplication?

**EDIT:** Here's the relevant code:

```
// gatsby-node.js

export const createPages = async ({ graphql, actions: { createPage } }) => {
  // This requires a GRAPHQL *string*
  const { data } = await graphql(sharedQuery);
  data.someData.forEach((pageData) => {
    createPage({
      path: pageData.path,
      component: pathUtil.resolve('src/templates/SomePage.js'),
      context: { pageData }
    });
  });
});


// pages/index.js

// This version requires a *tagged template literal*
export const query = sharedQuery;
const IndexPage = ({ data }) => { // ... page component that uses data
export default IndexPage;
```

Comment: Would you be able to post the entire contents of your `gatsby-node.js` file, or at least the segments that are relevant to the creation of your dynamic pages?

Comment: Is your intention to use the query for the purpose of a staticQuery in a component?

Comment: @bronson I added the relevant segments.  @ksav no, I have no desire to use `staticQuery`.  In my page I just want to use the standard `export const query` approach (and then have a `data` prop passed in to the page component), while on `gatsby-node.js` I want to use the `graphql` function provided as an argument to `createPages`.  The former expects a tagged template literal, the latter expects a string.

Comment: I understand. But still a bit confused as to what kind of data you might want shared between a page you are creating in `gatsby-node.js` and another page. Some kind of template data?

Comment: Actually, that's a good point.  I'm importing a non-Gatsby app into Gatsby, and it was setup to share a query for "all Foos" (the front page listed links to Foo pages, and the pages used a subset of the data for their Foo) ... but it seems more Gatsby-like to just use two separate queries.  I'm still curious (just academically though now) if it's possible to re-use query strings in different places (tagged vs. not) in Gatsby.

Comment: I guess the answer to that probably lies in how gatsby gathers all the page and static queries during the build process. But if it is shared data that needs to be queried, i think it *could* be a candidate for a static query that goes into a template.